# Getting same ID for all articles in loop after stripping slashes

Tags: php

I had trouble stripping \ from the code with stripslashes but finally figured it out as you can see in the code. This works great except that now every post title has the same story id (SID). For each row, the title title and category are correct, but if you click on the title they all have the same SID and go to the same article. I'm hoping this is an easy adjustment since this was the only way to remove the \ in the story_name.

```
foreach ($row2 as $all2) {
$stp = stripslashes($all2['story_name']);
echo '<tr>';
echo "<td><a href=\"http://example.com/main?writing=$all[SID]\">$stp</a>
</td>";
echo "<td>$all2[category]</td>";
```

Comment: It's a querystring, did  you try just urlencoding it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referencing `$all`, while your row item is `$all2` Is that correct ?
If not, try to change to `$all2[SID]`.

You may also try this code, so you won't need to use the backslashes to escape some characters

```
echo '<td><a href="http://example.com/main?writing='.$all2['SID'].'">'.$stp.'</a></td>';
```